# import img to data base

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, insert

I developing a code for uploading images to database.

Images are saved in a folder (img) and in db is the path to the image

I have a function to generate a random name for each image and this is where my problem arises, the image is sent to the destination folder but only have name, and no extension of the image ( jpeg, png ...) and can not show ...

```
if(count($error) == 0){

preg_match( "/\.(gif|bmp| png| jpg|jpeg){1}$/i", $imagem["name"], $ext);

$nameImg = md5(uniqid(time () ) ).".".$ext[1];

$pathImg ="img/".$nameImg;

move_uploaded_file($img ["tmp_name"], $pathImg);

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES ( ' ', ' ".$name. " ', ' ".$email. "', ' ".$nameImg. "') ");
```

What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: For starters, add some error catching. Then, what ***exactly*** isn't working?

Comment: You don't need an extension to show the image. `<img src="animage" />` should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the `preg_match` pattern. I removed the whitespaces and `{1}` which correspons to only 1 symbol.

```
preg_match( "/\.(gif|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i", $imagem["name"], $ext);
```

Comment: thank you! with this change now saves the image with the extension! (1a70e808a99af4ad1391d3c691b5f5ca.png)

But if trying to show the image continues to fail!


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id DESC");



while ($user = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {

 

 echo "<img src=' img/".$user-> imagem. " ' />";

}

?>

Comment: Yeah, so you gotta press a tick near my answer :D

Comment: And so what? By pressing it you will not lose anything.

Comment: pressing where? sorry but I'm new at this! today is my first day in stackoverflow!!! :)

Comment: Look at my answer -> near rating there is a white tick. Just press it and it will turn green. Thats how an answer is accepted :D

Comment: errors do not appear but the images are: [link](http://posterlovesfantage.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/thingy.png)

Comment: Just check the `src` attribute. You have to set it properly. When you have folders, you must go down in directories.

Comment: the images are on the folder (img)                                      echo "<img src='img/".$user->imagem."' />";

Comment: And the directory of your webpage?

Comment: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Comment: Pretty hard to explain as I cannot see what is going on :/

Comment: yes, I understand! the display appears: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the following to retrieve the file names extension, then add it on to the end.

```
$ext = pathinfo($imagem['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$pathImg ="img/".$nameImg.".".$ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the ER before png and before jpg. It is probably the error. Also you could try to check if you've got an extension before to move the file.
P.S. what $imagem contains?

Comment: $imagem = $_FILES['imagem']; already works :) but I can not show  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id DESC"); while ($user = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) { echo "<img src=' img/".$user-> imagem. " ' />"; } ?>